# Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using this [library](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android) for database operations. I faced an exception. When i try to run 
"contentsDao.queryForAll();", i got "Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed." exception.

My Code:

```
private Dao contentsDao = getDao(L_Content.class); 
public List getAllContents(String searchQuery)
    {
        try {
            if (searchQuery == null) {
                return contentsDao.queryForAll();
            } else {
                if (contentsQuery == null) {
                    contentsQuery= makeContentsQuery(false);
                }
                String nameParameter = searchQuery == null ? "%%" : "%"+searchQuery.trim()+"%";
                contentsQuery.setArgumentHolderValue(0,nameParameter);
                return contentsDao.query(contentsQuery);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Logcat output:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:108)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:316)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:142)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:163)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.(SelectIterator.java:55)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:232)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:181)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:113)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:239)
at ak.detaysoft.yeryuzudergidis.DatabaseApi.getAllContents(DatabaseApi.java:469)
at ak.detaysoft.yeryuzudergidis.DataApi.isLibraryMustBeEnabled(DataApi.java:201)
at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onKeyDown(MuPDFActivity.java:2414)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3147)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2831)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2438)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4582)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4537)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4421)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2480)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2074)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2065)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2457)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/55

Comment: Make sure to call cursor.close() on every Cursor object SQLite returns upon your queries. Your code snip is incomplete so can't tell where the "leak" is exactly.